# PHP: show position between students

Tags: php, mysql

I have a school project which I am about to finish, but I'm stuck on how to show position of a student in class according to highest total marks he/she gets.

Here is the table `(exam_record)` which contains some records of marks. In this result I want to say John is in position `1` out of `3` students. Anyone please help.

```
id   name  math   history   history geo  pds  average    total_marks
003  John  90     100       90      100  88   93.6       468
002  Joan  100    60        70      83   90   60.6       403  
005  Wily  80     58        90      60   90   75.6       378
```

Comment: Did you just want to retrieve the record of  **John**?

Comment: What are you looking for? Someone to write this code for you? Not going to happen; move on please.

Comment: order by total_marks

Answer (score 2):

I recently did this at work !! =)

```
select @rank:=@rank+1 as rank, total_students.total_students as out_of, name, total_marks
from
(select exam_record.*, @rank:=0 from exam_record
order by total_marks desc) sorted_exam_record,
(select count(id) as total_students from exam_record) total_students
```

Answer (score 2):

Hi You can use this `query` (but this `query` is useful only when no two student has same record)

```
SELECT id, name, total_marks, FIND_IN_SET( total_marks, (
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT( total_marks
ORDER BY total_marks DESC ) 
FROM exam_record)
) AS rank
FROM exam_record order by total_marks desc
```

or you can define a `variable` and can use this simple `query`(also useful when marks of two or more students are same)

```
SET @i=0;
SELECT id, name, total_marks, @i:=@i+1 AS rank 
 FROM exam_record
 ORDER BY total_marks DESC;
```